# Samsung Internet matches justify-content: space-evenly but doesn't support it

Tags: css

Samsung Internet matches this code even though on Flexbox it doesn't support `space-evenly`. Any ideas on how to get around this?

```
@supports (justify-content: space-evenly) {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean Samsung internet? Their websites?

Comment: @Rarblack The default browser supplied on every Samsung device. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.app.sbrowser&hl=en

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=justify-content - you gotta work around it, but gotta ask: how many users use samsung default browser (get info from your analytics)

Comment: @AIqbalRaj Thanks. Sadly there's enough that we must consider the browser. At least for graceful degradation. I wish manufacturers would stop pushing out their own browsers that just lag behind the leaders #rant. Anyway, it seems the "best" solution is to use `center` on mobile and `space-around` for our case.

Comment: I share your sentiments around the donkeys and horses of the browser world... But in the quest to get personalized data to gain competitive advantage, I doubt that these would stop - Good luck to you around this issue :)